# Magento Filter Page

Tags: list, magento, categories

We want to add a class to the category filter page on a specific attribute.

An example is below, we would like to add a class called "Man" to the DT.

```
<dt class="even">Manufacturer</dt>
<dd class="even"><ol>
            <li>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="$(this).next().click()">
                <a onclick="$(this).previous().checked = true;" href="/filter/test">Apple</a>
                            (1)
        </li>
            <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" onclick="$(this).next().click()">
                <a onclick="$(this).previous().checked = true;" href="/filter/test/">HTC</a>
                            (1)
        </li>
    </ol></dd>
```

We are trying to add a class, so it would look like the example below:

```
<dt class="even Man">Manufacturer</dt>
```

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a file located at:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml
```

Here you can put those classes in dt elements based on some if conditions, although it's not a good practice.